# What is the field selector syntax with nested grouping in sphinx query

Tags: sphinx

I have function that creates sphinx query based on its params. ANDs and ORs might be nested, and specific field defined.

So really simple example:
article with indexed title and content.
(title: ('aaa' AND 'bbb')) AND 'ccc'
would naturally create:
"(@title aaa bbb) ccc"

It doesn't work, because @title's effect doesn't end with closing parentheses but follows to "ccc". The right query would be:
"@title aaa bbb @* ccc" or "ccc @title aaa bbb"
but I don't control neither the order nor the nesting of terms, so the part that generates "@title aaa bbb" doesn't know if there will be "non-field ccc" later, and always putting "@*", just in case, also fails, when it's last term.

Is there any way to safely enclose @field selector effect?

Edit:
This question is only relevant for versions before 2.1.7.
Turns out there was a bug in sphinx, related to fields selector inside group, that was fixed in 2.1.7:

http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1917

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do what you already found `(@title aaa bbb) ccc` ? ie if a field search, just surround in brackets.

Simple and effective.

---

or

> always putting "@*", just in case, also fails, when it's last term.

Just remove it, if the last term, pretty easy in most langauges to strip something off the end of a string.

Comment: Currently it really works, but before 2.1.7 it didn't.

http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1917